# Remove-DistributionGroupMember - Specify a unique user

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to remove a bunch of members from a distribution list in exchange using powershell. I originally was using the alias value to specify the members but ran into errors saying there were multiple members with a specified alias. So I am trying to use something else to uniquely id these members.

According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996367.aspx) documentation, the Get-DistributionGroupMember has many of the same fields under identity as the [Remove-DistributionGroupMember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998016.aspx) cmdlet has under member, but I am having trouble getting any of them other than alias to work. Here is my code so far:

```
foreach ($member in Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $selecteddl | Select-Object Alias) {
        Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $selecteddl -Member $member.alias -Confirm:$False
    }
```

That is the code that produces the error of duplicate members. If I change both of the "alias" properties to "guid" I get a different error:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Member'. Cannot
>   convert the "4ed0987f-7c86-48e7-8f47-ca9ad731e2fd" value of type
>   "System.Guid" to type
>   "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.GeneralRecipientIdParameter".
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindin...mationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Remove-DistributionGroupMember

Is there somthing that I should be doing differently to get around this issue?
I am very new to powershell so I will take any additional tips you have for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: you can simplify the operation with this. Again, this will remove ALL members so you better do some filtering before you piping to Remove-DistributionGroupMember.

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember $selecteddl | Remove-DistributionGroupMember $selecteddl -Confirm:$false
```

According to the docs Alias should be a legitimate value. I can't test this now but this should work. Keep in mind that you are removing ALL group members.

```
foreach ($member in Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $selecteddl) 
{
  Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $selecteddl -Member $member -Confirm:$False
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I will give that a try. We actually do want to completely clear the lists, so that is probably perfect. I actually had found a temporary solution to the problem by saving the guid to a var casted as a string, then using that for the member. I am not sure why that worked but putting it in normally didn't work. Will report back with whether your solution worked.

Comment: With your top method I receive this error: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (DOMAIN.../LAST, FIRST:PSObject) [Remove-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Remove-DistributionGroupMember

Comment: What's your Exchange version?

Comment: I've been testing on the same version. $selecteddl contains the dl name (string)?